# Windows 8 Market App, JS, access remote XML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, windows-8

I've ran into Same Origin Policy issues before while doing standard web development.  I usually end up writing a vb.net web service as a proxy.  However, now that I'm trying to dabble in Windows 8 development using Javascript (due to familiararity) I'm wondering what my options are to avoid the issue.

All I need to do is fetch a remote XML file and display information from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a WinJS.xhr call to the xml file directly without problem as long as you have the Internet (Client) capability enabled (which it is by default).  I do it all the time in several applications.

I'm assuming all you want to do is download an xml doc and work with the data.

You should check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441295.aspx if you looking at sending cross document messages.  If you want the deep discussion on dynamic web content, security contexts, etc. - this is a good place to start, though a bit dated http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-476T

Comment: Is there a problem if the external XML file is served in a non-secure (HTTP not HTTPS)?